# What are the differences between BLEU score and METEOR?

Tags: machine-translation, bleu, opennmt, nmt

I am trying to understand the concept of evaluating the machine translation evaluation scores.

I understand how what BLEU score is trying to achieve. It looks into different n-grams like BLEU-1,BLEU-2, BLEU-3, BLEU-4 and try to match with the human written translation.

However, I can't really understand what METEOR score is for evaluating MT quality. I am trying understand the rationale intuitively. I am already looking into different blog post but cant really figure out.

How these two evaluation metrics are different and how they are relevant?

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

METEOR is a modification of the standard **precisions-recall type of evaluation** for MT. You want all words from the translation hypothesis to have a counterpart in the reference translation (precision) and everything from the reference translation in the translation hypothesis (recall). The recall is weighted as 9-times more important than the precision.

For this, (monolingual) **alignment between the words in the hypothesis and the reference** is needed. This is not that easy with machine translation because the translation might use different words to express the same. For this, METEOR uses a table with word n-gram paraphrases, which are language-specific.

Finally, there is a **penalty** for the alignment being ugly. If you randomly shuffled the translation, you could still get a perfect alignment, but the sentence is obviously broken. The penalty is a one minus the cube of the number of continuous word chunks aligned over a total number of aligned words.